# Python Tensorflow/Keras: How to go from 3D input to 2D output of a specific size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a sequential neural network, in the style of an autoencoder at the moment, that takes an image of a specific set of dimensions, encodes it, extracts the feature vector for use elsewhere, and then decodes it again. I have however trained it on a set of sequential images, and the target image for the autoencoder to recreate is the next one in the sequence instead of the original image it was given. This works fairly well, but I want to see if I can improve the system by providing multiple input images instead of a single one, but I'm not sure what the best method would be to go about doing that.

Given I have a set of these sequential images, of shape [xdim, ydim];
I currently have two possible approaches. The first being to treat the inputs as a single 3D array (shape [xdim, ydim, num_inputs]), thereby maintaining the sequential network, but I'm not sure how to ensure the output of the decoder then maintains the dimensions of an individual image (eg. shape [xdim, ydim]) instead of something 3-dimensional.

The second is to make a sequential encoder for each input and then decoding the result. If I do this, I'm aware I should concatenate the inputs somewhere, and I assume I should do this after, but I once again don't know if I can then ensure the output of the decoder then maintains the dimensions of an individual image?

I haven't been able to find great documentation on this, and I'm not as well-versed in keras or tensorflow as I'd like to be, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to make it clear: your input images are grayscale images? The shape is just (H, W) and not (H, W, C) with e.g C=3 for RGB ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, they are effectively greyscale images, shape is just (H, W)